# List Index value is -1 even after selecting all items in listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, checkbox, listbox

**Background:**
I have a userform in MS Access with a MultiColumn (2 colums) listbox, One checkbox and a command button.
The Multicolumn listbox provides output via a query, the check box (name- Select all) used to select all the lines in the listbox and the command button is to get the values selected in the listbox and delete them.

**Problem:**
The Select All check box checks all the selected items in the listbox, but when i use the command button to delete the values i still get row index as -1

Code behind the checkbox

```
Me.List45.SetFocus
If Me.Check55.Value = True Then 
    For i = 0 To Me.List45.ListCount
    Me.List45.Selected(i) = True
    Next i
Else
    For i = 0 To Me.List45.ListCount
    Me.List45.Selected(i) = False
    Next i

End If
```

Code in the Command button

```
rowIndex = Me.List45.ListIndex
If rowIndex = -1 Then
MsgBox "Select an Item in List Box!", vbApplicationModal
Exit Sub
End If
```

If i select any value in the list box and try to delete it works fine - any suggestions what i am missing here.

Comment: Do you have `.MultiSelect` set to `Simple` or `Extended` for the `ListBox`?

Comment: I believe since multiselect is enabled, the `ListIndex` is not being populated as it cannot hold more than one value. Try `List45.ItemsSelected.Count > 0`.

Comment: @braX - Multiselect is extended

Comment: @KostasK. Yes, - I updated the list index to ItemsSelected.Count and it works - Thank you so mcuh for the help.